# Bounded analytic function that can not be extended to the boundary of the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to find a Luzin example as promised on the website [encyclopediaofmath](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Luzin_examples), but I don't have access to Luzin collected works, which are referred to in the article. In particular, I don't even read Russian, so I doubt I could make much use from them. Does anyone know the actual counterexample and could explain the construction process? I don't need a proof that most can be extended, but would simply like to see an actual example of a function where it cannot be extended to the boundary on some points, potentially even on an infinite (uncountably?) subset of measure $0$ of the unit disc.

Cheers for any help on this.

Comment: Read about 'Natural Boundary' in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748967/prove-that-fz-sum-n-1-infty-exp-nz-has-no-analytic-continuation/3749006#3749006

Comment: Have a look at the answer I have posted in the above question, does this answer your question?

Comment: You can find it also [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/147128862.pdf#page=46). Although I think the $u$ inside the Poisson integral should be a $g$.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Unfortunately not, since this given function is not bounded anymore on the disc. I'm looking for a function that can be extended almost everywhere, but not everywhere.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: @plop The given example has radial limit $=0$ rather than not existing. I don't think it qualifies here. I also don't see how I could change the construction to obtain a function where the limit does not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am still trying to find an example. Natural boundary is defined via non existent analytic continuation, but I am looking for a function which can't even be continuously extended to the boundary. I don't want to have any more than the boundary, no disc centered on a boundary point, just non existent radial limits to the boundary. I can't seem to find it in chapter 16, at least not on my first glance.

Comment: $\sum z^{2^{n}}$ is such an example and Rudin explains why this example works.

Comment: Fatou's Theorem shows that for bounded analytic functions in the unit disc, radial limits may fail to exist only on a set of circle measure zero (which must be topologically a $G_{\delta\sigma}$), but it it is not known for which such sets $E$ the limit exists on $\partial \mathbb D-E$ and not on $E$;  Lusin theorem tells us that any $E$ of measure zero is contained in an $E_1$ as above, while it is known is that any $E$ measure zero and $F_{\sigma}$ works; the book The Theory of Cluster Sets by Lohwater and Collingswood has these results (not that hard but a bit tedious) in chapter 2

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, I'll check it out!